# Facebook SDK Setup

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to add the Facebook SDK to my app, I've followed every step.

the only problem I have is that the the the code that I need to add to the AppDelegate is in Objective C and I'm using Swift. I don't know how to convert the Objective C code to swift, Can you help me?

This is the code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
   [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                     openURL:url
                                           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                  annotation:annotation];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try facebook login code :

**Appdelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {    
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dict : NSDictionary!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.containsObject("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                    fbLoginManager.logOut()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    self.dict = result as NSDictionary
                    println(result)
                    println(self.dict)
                    NSLog(self.dict.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as String)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: finishlaunchingwithoptions gives me this error: http://postimg.org/image/51yv7nsuh/

Comment: you have added this method two time @OmerN.

Comment: it works but I have one more question: some of the data, such as the first name shows up like this: "\U05e2\U05d5\U05de\U05e8", why?